# How can I infinitely iterate through a jsonArray using Kotlin without getting a 'Val cannot be reassigned' error?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

I am having to infinitely iterate through for loop of a jsonArray using kotlin.

```
for (i in 0 until arrayValue.length()) {
// Certain operations
if (i.equals(arrayValue.length())){
   // reset value of i, to 0
}
}
```

But if i change value to 0 like (i = 0),
It shows error.

> Val cannot be reassigned

Any help, on how to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off using a while loop:

```
while(true) {
  arrayValue.forEach { 
    // your code here
  }
}
```

I prefer `forEach` to `for` loops, but all you could use either in the while loop.

Comment: Will it continue from start(0) even after it has completed its iteration of the last element in array?  I kind of need it to be an infinite loop kind of thing..

Comment: @Android_Dev yes, the code in the answer above will be an infinite loop. The condition in the while loop is always true, so it will keep re-iterating the array indefinitely.